# Pass event from one function to other inline function called agianst XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am not able to pass the event which is passed in func to the inline function called against `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`. While passing the event from function `func` to the inline function, it says undefined value. PFB inline comments for the same.

```
event.currentTarget.addEventListener("click", func, false); 
function func(event){
   var data1; 
   var str=event.currentTarget.textContent; //here variable value for str is   coming successfully.
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(event)
             {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                  alert("event is"+event.currentTarget.textContent); //here event.currentTarget.textContent is coming undefined . Is there a way to get the value here similar to variable str?

                   data1= xmlhttp.responseText;
                   }
              }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","Jr6?q="+str,true); //here simply calling the servlet to get the data which is stored in data1 above.
  xmlhttp.send();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try remove the "event" argument from inner function, and simply use the var "str":

```
event.currentTarget.addEventListener("click", func, false); 
function func(event){
    var data1; 
    var str=event.currentTarget.textContent;
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert("event is" + str); 
            data1= xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Jr6?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

you can read about Closures here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: this way I am able to access the value of str inside my second function , but I want to access the outer event inside inner function something like this :     function func(event1){   var myEvents = []; myEvents.push(event1);   ev = myEvents.shift(); var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(ev){     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){  alert("ondition"+ev.currentTarget.textContent);}}} //here my objective is just to get the value of ev which should be equivalent to the outer function event . is there a way for this?

Comment: Sure. just use Closures.
Remove the "ev" parameter from the inner function.
I recommend you to read about the Closures and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument **hides** your first argument.

Look, how those names should be changes:

```
function func(myFirstEvent){
   var str = myFirstEvent.currentTarget.textContent; 
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(mySecondEvent) {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           alert("event is" + myFirstEvent.currentTarget.textContent);
```

Comment: Tried with  this as well as you suggested like changing the name as event2 then printing alert("event is"+event2.currentTarget.textContent); //still its coming as undefined. :(

Comment: @swatisachan See my edited answer :) Consider accepting it if it solved your problem. Or tell me what can I do to help your further :)

Comment: this way also it did not work for me, I wrote in other way to get the outer function event inside inner function but even my way also did not work. Its below :     function func(event1){ var myEvents = []; myEvents.push(event1); ev = myEvents.shift(); var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(ev){ if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ alert("ondition"+ev.currentTarget.textContent);}}} //here my objective is just to get the value of ev which should be equivalent to the outer function event . here again this alert is giving undefined .

Comment: please provide help for the same :(